# jQuery Validate - digits of min length of 10 or 13?

Tags: jquery-validate

How do I create a custom validation rule for the jquery validate plugin that checks against the user's input as either 10 or 13 digits? Thanks much for the help.

Comment: So it won't allow minlength 11 or 12. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple sample of validation

```
$("#FormToValidatePhoto").validate({
  rules: {
   Title: { minlength: 10, maxlength: 13 }
  },
  messages: {
   Title: { minlength: "Min is 10", maxlength: "Max is 13" }}
});
```

Comment: actually I need it to pass validation that either min length is 13 OR min length is 10, not max length as 13.

Comment: well sorry, then create the custom validation. 
if ($('#fiel').length > 10 && ($('#fiel').length != 11 && $('#fiel').length != 12)) return true;